# table inside the div, table cannot be placed exactly on div

Tags: html, css

When I have placed the table inside the div element, there is 0.565px gap.

I want to place that table exactly on div.

```
<div style="width: 72.956%; border:1px solid; padding:25px">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div style="padding:0px; margin:0px; border:1px solid" >
        <table style="width: 100%; margin:0px; padding:0px; border:1px solid">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>05/15/1991</td>
              <td> ALKI</td>
              <td>1 </td> 
              <td>$6.89</td>d>
              <td> 1003 </td> 
            </tr> 
          </tbody> 
       </table> 
     </div> 
    </div> 
   </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: can you provide some demo or fiddle?

Comment: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: Hi Kalai, On Stack Overflow, better explained question can be better ansered. Create a demo at `https://jsfiddle.net` or paste ur code here

Comment: <div style="width: 72.956%; border:1px solid; padding:25px">
<div>
    <div>
        <div style="padding:0px; margin:0px; border:1px solid" >
            <table style="width: 100%; margin:0px; padding:0px; border:1px solid">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                                <td>05/15/1991</td><td> ALKI</td><td>1 </td>                 <td>$6.89</td>d><td> 1003 </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the div display as table

```
div
{
display :table;
}
```

then table exactly rendered on div element

Answer (score 0):

There might be a couple of reasons. Try using these and please give us more information if it's not working.

CSS:

```
div{
   padding:0;
}

table{
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: i have set this value but there is gap

Answer (score 0):

Try cellpadding and cellspaceing 0